# NameHasNoOwner warning at NetworkManager

Tags: wireless, network-manager, dbus

My syslog shows various NetworkManager warnings on startup, and I am wondering whether these warning indicate any real problem. Here's a collection of such:

```
Oct 14 15:15:43 lati NetworkManager[819]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.27': no such name
Oct 14 15:15:43 lati NetworkManager[819]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.27': no such name
```

---

My network cards:

```
      *-network               
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 19
           bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
           logical name: eth2
           version: 04
           serial: ec:f4:bb:55:4f:c5
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 32 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.7-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
           resources: irq:60 memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e3c000-f7e3cfff ioport:f080(size=32)
      *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Wireless 7260
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
           logical name: wlan2
           version: 73
           serial: f8:16:54:0c:6d:31
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-40-generic firmware=25.228.9.0 ip=10.0.0.144 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
           resources: irq:65 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

My wifi card:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
```

It is not blocked:

```
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

and `dmesg` shows a firmware bug:

```
[    0.129867] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
```

Comment: Can't find anything regarding the bus error. Regarding the last one (FW bug): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1275985/comments/4